# Graphviz arrowhead doesn't work when dir=back

Tags: graphviz

I can't figure out how to change the tail of an edge.

No problem with the arrow head, for example this works fine

```
digraph foo {  
    x->y [arrowhead=odot]  
}
```

But since I want to change the tail I tried to invert the direction:

```
digraph foo {  
    x->y [arrowhead=odot dir=back]  
}
```

This doesn't work, the arrow gets back to the default style.

Also the arrowtail attribute seems not to work, I always get the default style

```
digraph foo {  
    x->y [arrowtail=odot]  
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711106/3788685) answer it may offer something of use.

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it - not all combinations of [`dir`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:dir), `arrowhead` and `arrowtail` are valid.

Here's what works for which [`dir`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:dir) value:

```
dir      arrowhead  arrowtail
-----------------------------
forward      x
back                    x
both         x          x
none
```

Therefore, the following should work in your case:

```
digraph foo {  
    x->y [arrowtail=odot, dir=back] 
}
```

[`dir`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:dir) determines which arrows are allowed to be displayed. Which end of the arrow is the head and which end is considered to be the tail doesn't change.